# 8051 micro controller to transmit data to ZigBee

Tags: serial-port, 8051, zigbee

My problem is that I do not know how to transmit an AT command from 8051 micro controller to [ZigBee](http://www.zigbee.org) serially. Any tips on how I can do that?

But for the time being, I shall try to transmit a string of data using array from the micro controller to the computer and see using hyper terminal. Currently I can only transmit a character 'A' continuously from 8051 to hyper terminal on the computer.

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Please try to narrow it down to a specific technical problem.

Comment: ok i just simply want to transmit a string of data from 8051 to computer. thanks.

Comment: Now, i can transmit a string of data to the computer and seeing it trough hyperterminal. I used an if statement, like if SBUF=='A'. i only want to transmit once whenever the micro controller receives 'A'. But the problems now is that the string keeps transmitting. i think this is because that'A' is still in the SBUF? Do i need to clear to SBUF so that the transmission can stop? and how do i do that?

Comment: Whatever toolchain you're using for the 8051 should have a serial library included, with an API you can use to send strings.  Otherwise, you will need to read the documentation on the serial registers used to configure the port, load characters into the transmit buffer, and know when it's safe to load the next character.  Googling for "8051 serial communication in C" turns up numerous code samples.

Answer (score 0):

Sending a string via any 8051 should look the same.

First, initialize the serial port the good way (assume it's ok if you can send 'A').

Then, you have to initialize either a table or a pointer.

```
UC *ucText = "Hello World";
UC ucText[] = "Hello World";
```

Create a single function which input parameter is a UC variable (ucSend can be 'A' or anything) and transmit only once when called

```
void vTx232 (UC ucSend)
 {
    while (TI);    //While last TX not done
    SBUF = ucSend; //Character into TX buffer
 }
```

Then, a second function to transmit a string which calls the above function. The input string is the variable you created earlier.

```
void vTxString (UC *ucpString)
 {
   while (*ucpString!= 0x00)   //While string not at it's end
    {
      vTx232(*ucpString);       //Send the actual string character
      ucpString++;              //Increments string
    }
 }
```